# How does one use the expression »Mich hat’s voll erwischt!«?

Tags: meaning, phrase

Beim Lesen des Buchs "Unser Immunsystem: Wie es Bakterien, Viren & Co. abwehrt und wie wir es stärken (German Edition)" von Hendrik Streeck

Ich lese auf Seite 7 die Wendung »Mich hat’s voll erwischt!«
Das bedeutet auf Englisch "That's got me".

Kann man bei Corona, Erkältung oder Grippe »Mich hat’s voll erwischt!« sagen?

In welchem Kontext wird »Mich hat’s voll erwischt!« benutzt? Zum Beispiel, könnte man über ein Bier sagen »Mich hat’s voll erwischt!«?

Comment: Ich finde es sehr schwer, die Frage zu verstehen.

Comment: I made an edit to your question. Please review whether I didn't change the meaning of your question. I'm especially not clear I got it right on the last paragraph.

Comment: What would *Mich hat’s voll erwischt!* in a kontext with beer mean?

Comment: I have no clue and would answer that part with 'no'.

Comment: "Man hat's nicht leicht, aber leicht hat's einen [erwischt]."

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Die umgangssprachliche Wendung sagt erst einmal nur aus, dass Du plötzlich massiv unter dem Einfluss von etwas stehst.

Dieses *etwas* kann aber sehr verschieden sein:

- ein Erkältungs- oder Coronavirus (hier ist gemeint: heftige Symptome)
- plötzliche Verliebtheit
- der Nachbar am Tisch hat sein Bierglas umgeworfen und z. B. deine Hose hat alles abbekommen
- ein Regenguss hat die komplette Kleidung durchnässt

Für mehr Beispiele ist die [Korpussuche](https://www.dwds.de/r/?corpus=tsp&q=voll%20erwischt) von DWDS zu empfehlen:

Comment: Die Antwort ist sehr gut. Ich finde aber trotzdem, dass der Fragensteller erst einmal seine Frage etwas deutlicher ausarbeiten könnte.